# How to resolve this click conflict?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, click, robotframework

```
<div id="mainTag" class='mainTag'>
    <div id="subMainTag1" class="subMainTag1">
        <div id="subTag1" class="subTag1">
                   <Detail Explanation below>
        <div id="subTag1" class="subTag1">
                    <Same as above, only difference would be some text message >
         <div id="subTag1" class="subTag1">
                    <Same as above, only difference would be some text message>
```

**Detailed snippet of subtag1**

```
<div id="mainTag" class='mainTag'>
         <div id="subMainTag1" class="subMainTag1">
             <div id="subTag1" class="subTag1">
                 <div id="subTag2" class="subTag2">
                     <div id="subTag2A" class="subTag2A"></div>
                     <div id="datapreview" class="dataPreview">      <!-- These below lines will not be enabled/expanded -->
                         <div id="dataNote" class="dataNote">
                            <div id="titleBar" class="titleBar">
                                <span id="dataTime" class="datTime">9/10/2017 7:01 pm</span>
                                <div id="deleteButton" class="deleteButton">
                                    <img class="someimg" src="someimg">
</div>
</div>
                            <div id="contentDiv" class="contentDiv">
                                <div id="dataTitle" class="dataTitle">Some Data1</div>
                                <div id="dataContent" class="dataContent">Some Data1 Body text </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>     <!-- Lines will be disabled till here-->
</div>
</div>
```

On clicking on the subTag1, those disabled line gets enabled/expanded.

> Unable to click on `div` element.

```
//div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1']/div[1]
//div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1']/div[2]
//div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1']/div[3]
```

When I click on any of the above elements, it says WebDriverException:

> Message: unknown error: Element
>   //div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1'/div[2] is not clickable at
>   point (433, 239). Other element would receive the click:
>   //div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1'/div[2]   (Session info:
>   chrome=60.0.3112.113)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774
>   (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6
>   x86_64)

Comment: WHich element u want to click

Comment: You seem to be using `robotframework`. Would a plain Java based Answer cater to your Question?

Comment: @iamsankalp89 : I want to click all the elements 1, 2 and 3. By clicking on any of this div element, the corresponding next child node gets expanded/enabled (the inner div element for each of these would be having different text).

Comment: @DebanjanB: Yes, I am using robot framework.

Comment: where did you close 2nd '[' ?

Comment: @Kapil : ok, got it. posted here wrongly.

Comment: In your xpath's, there are 3 opening brackets([) but only 2 closing brackets (])

Comment: What all options did you try? Show us your code.

Comment: After click the first div,  did you wait the expanding complete before you click the second div?

Comment: @yong : I think, I have tried adding sleep inbetween. That's a good catch. let me check it once again.When i try as div[1] and div[2] in Selenium IDE, that works perfectly.

Comment: @yong : That did the trick. Increased the sleep time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the given code structure there is no second or third sibling, they are children. You'll need to adjust your xpath to get the right node.

For example, locate the second 'div' anywhere within 'subMainTag1':

```
xpath=(//div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1']//div)[2]
```

If you forgot the closing div's in your code example, adding the brackets should be enough:

```
xpath=(//div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1']/div)[2]
```

Comment: How does it make different from //div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1']/div[2] ?

Comment: '//' tells xpath to search anywhere within the given path, so in your example search any 'div' within div[@id='subMainTag1'].

When you put the xpath between brackets it tells xpath to look for the entire path and then look for the nth occurence. Robot Framework won't recognize the xpath when it starts with a bracket so you have to make it explicit:
    xpath=(//div[@id="mainTag"]/div[@id='subMainTag1']//div)[2]